# How to run script via cron and get same results as terminal? (Centos 7.2)

Tags: linux, cron

I have a complicated question (I understood that's related to environment variables).
I'm running a script via termial as follows: "bash install_version.sh"

script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
/root/RADview_linux_6_4_0_* << 'EOF'
o
1
LAB - 16GB Minimum Server
sleep 120
EOF
```

And it works fine (4 folder were created as it should be).
After that, I tried to run the script via cron and only 1 folder was created (instead of 4).
Crob contains:

```
47 14 * * 1-5 bash /root/nightlyBuild/install_version.sh
```

Anyone can advise?

Comment: Can you, please, edit you question so that we can better see what's in your script and in the crontab line ? The 1st line of your script looks strange to me : this is usually something like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. Your crontab line is suspect too : do you write it directly in a file or using the `crontab` utility ?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry about my question I don't know how to write it in your way. about crontab, I'm using with crontab utility (crontab -e).